# Change content of a div based on an array within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Pastebin of index.html: http://pastebin.com/kdKFqTxe
Just copy and paste that and run it (this works but with some broken img links & no css).
With regards to the pastebin, just click on a node, and then click the first broken image below the video. What should happen is a dialogue box should appear with links to articles (from tubeArray). All relevant code is pasted below.

I'm trying to dynamically change the contents of a div when I click an image. The image has it's respective id (the first index in the inner array) within the first inner array there's another array (index 3). I want to populate my div (id="articleLinks") with those links using JQuery when the image is clicked.

**JavaScript & JQuery:**

The tube array. *Note: the first index of each element in tubeArray is the ID & the news articles aren't linked to anything particular. Only interested in tubeArray[0] & tubeArray[4]

```
 var tubeArray = [
            ['UQ', -27.495134, 153.013502, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/uZ2SWWDt8Wg",  
                [
                ["example.com", "Brisbane students protest university fee hikes"],
                ["example.com", "Angry protests over UQ student union election"],
                ]
            ],
            ['New York', 40.715520, -74.002036, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/JG0wmXyi-Mw",
                [
                ["example.com" , "NY taxpayers’ risky Wall Street bet: Why the comptroller race matters"]
                ]
            ],
            ['To The Skies', 47.09399, 15.40548, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/tfEjTgUmeWw", 
                [
                ["example.com","Battle for Kobane intensifies as Islamic State uses car bombs, Syrian fighters execute captives"],
                ["example.com","Jihadists take heavy losses in battle for Syria's Kobane"]
                ]
            ],
            ['Fallujah', 33.101509, 44.047308, "http://www.youtube.com/embed/V2EOMzZsTrE", 
                [
                ["example.com","Video captures family cat saving California boy from dog attack"],
                ["example.com","Fines of £20,000 for dogs that chase the postman"]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

A for loop which goes through each element in tubeArray then assigns *id* to the first index. Also an image that calls the function *myFunctionId* which takes the parameter *this.id*.

```
for (i = 0; i < tubeArray.length; i++) {
    var id = tubeArray[i][0];

    //other code

    '<img src="img.png" onclick="myFunctionId(this.id);" id="' + id + '">' +

    //other code
}

function myFunctionId (id) {
        journal = id; 
        alert(journal) //just a test

        //I want to search through tubeArray with the id and find the matching inner array. 

        //I then want to loop through the innerArray and append to my html a link using JQuery.
        $('#articleLinks').append("<a href='"+innerArray[0]+"'>"+innerArray[1]+'</a>'); // use CSS to break lines
       }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="articleLinks">
    <a href="http:/www.google.com">Example Link</a><br>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried to simplify & cut out as much as I can so it's readable.

Comment: with the pastebin... what... there's so much going on.  what am I clicking on?  What do I want to happen?

Comment: that top black bar is incredibly annoying, btw.

Comment: With all this code, exactly what does one do to trigger the action (what do you click on), what exactly do you want to have happen on the click and what exactly is it doing now?  You need to remember that we know nothing about what you want to do or how your page works.

Comment: scale your code down to a minimal example and put it into jsfiddle.net along with steps to replicate and expectations

Comment: i think... we click on the red dots.  not sure.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin & jfriend00 yes, sorry I realise that I need a bit of context. Updated the intro to explain what I'm trying to do. It's actually an app being built in phonegap hence the black bar (no css included since just index file). Yeah click on the dots :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
function myFunctionId (id) { 
   console.log(tubeArray); 
   tubeArray.forEach(function(entry) {
       if (entry[0]==id) { 
         entry[4].forEach(function(innerArray){
            $('#articleLinks').append("<a href='"+innerArray[0]+"'>"+innerArray[1]+'</a>'); // use CSS to break lines
         });
         return;
       }
   });                 
}
```

it makes it look like this for me... you're gonna have to handle that encoding issue.  with the apostrophe.  there are a lot of ways to handle it...

[image]

so.... if it was me... which it's not.  but if it was... i would use an associative array instead of a numerically indexed one because it's easier to read the code and understand what you're using and where and how and things and stuff.

```
tubeArray = {
    'UQ' :      { 'location': [-27.495134, 153.013502], 
                  'youtube':  "example.com/embed/uZ2SWWDt8Wg",  
                  'articles': [["example.com/queensland/brisbane-students-protest-university-fee-hikes-20140521-zrk8o.html", "Brisbane students protest university fee hikes"],
                               ["example.com/content/2012/s3578878.htm", "Angry protests over UQ student union election"], ]
                },
    'New York': { 'location': [0.715520, -74.002036], 
                  'youtube':  "example.com/embed/JG0wmXyi-Mw",
                  'articles': [["example.com/2014/10/19/ny-taxpayers-risky-wall-street-bet-why-the-comptroller-race-matters/" , "NY taxpayers’ risky Wall Street bet: Why the comptroller race matters"]],
                 },
     }
```

Comment: I tried literally pasting in your solution and it doesn't work.

As for the associative array (it looks a lot better and I wish I would have done it that way initially).

Comment: @spamsaddle - that function was the only thing I changed and it did work for me.  Why didn't it work for you?  Errors or something else?  Also, what browser are you in?  take out that `console.log()` if you're in IE w/o developer tools open.

Comment: I just tested it... I recopied what was on pastebin.  Updated the function and nothing else.  It showed the box exactly as the image I have in my post.

Comment: ohhh... and hey, that articleLinks div or whatever, since you're appending, each time they click, it will always append and never clear out or reset.

Comment: No, sorry you're amazing. It was a problem on my end. Everything you did was perfect. You are my messiah, I'm sorry I ever doubted you m'lord.